# Фильтрация массива с объектами

Tags: javascript, массивы

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть массив с объектами который имеет вид:

```js
const arr =[
  { name: 123, ids: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] },
  { name: 456, ids: [8, 3, 4] },
]
```

И массив по которому нужно отфильтровать его (он меняется):

```js
const filt = [3, 5, 1];
```

На выходе ожидаю такой массив:

```js
[
  { name: 123, ids: [1, 3, 5] },
  { name: 456, ids: [3] },
]
```

Моя попытка была такой, но она неверная:

```js
const newArr = arr.filter((el) => el.ids.filter((el) => filt.includes(el)));

//в таком случае работает, но я изменяю массив, что мне не нужно…

const newArr = arr.filter((el) => {
  return (el.ids = el.ids.filter((el) => filt.includes(el)));
});
```

Comment: Возмьте ваш вариант и замените `const newArr = arr.filter` на `const newArr = arr.map`

Comment: @Swad К сожалению я получу тогда данные в виде массива с массивами но потеряю значения объектов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного модифицировал пример с учетом того, что в массиве `arr` может быть элемент, у которого ни один из `ids` не подпадает под критерий фильтра. Получается так:

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 123, ids: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] },
  { name: 456, ids: [8, 3, 4] },
  { name: 789, ids: [2] },
];

const filt = [3, 5, 1];

const out = arr
  .filter(item => item.ids.some(id => filt.includes(id)))
  .map(item => {
    return {
      ...item,
      ids: item.ids.filter(id => filt.includes(id))
    };
  });

console.log(JSON.stringify(out, null, 2));
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
[
  {
    "name": 123,
    "ids": [
      1,
      3,
      5
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": 456,
    "ids": [
      3
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Супер, спасибо большое, пойду вникать как работает...

Comment: @Moroshka пожалуйста! если что-то непонятно - спрашивайте, уточню ответ